# Updating a SharePoint List with InfoPath List?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath-forms-services, infopath2010

I want to update/create a SharePoint List using InfoPath. So far I have the form created and when I select the 'Submit' button I have set the program to indicate if the form was submitted successfully and I do receive this message. However, when I look at the SharePoint List where I indicated the program where I want the list to reside, there are no updates.

I am pulling data from the database and the conditions are set and the data queried is correct. Everything else will be a breeze as soon as I can figure out how to connect InfoPath List to the SharePoint List. Every where I am looking indicates this is not possible and unfortuatly it is seeming this way. There has to be some kind of work around. I have only been working with InfoPath and SharePoint for the last few months (literally), I may need someone to walk me through this as no one else in the office knows these programs.

Comment: Check this out.  Saving InfoPath results is standard functionality.  See this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826993 -- Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to make your InfoPath form call a web service. In the web service you can do whatever you want; create a list, create a list item or any other thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help if you explained a little better what exactly you're trying to accomplish...

Are you trying to CREATE a list or UPDATE a list in SharePoint?  When you query the database, are you trying to insert new values in an existing list or create a new list and insert the values.

You could probably accomplish this (inserting rows into an existing list) by writing code behind the list form and then publishing it as a sandboxed or Admin Approved form.

If this is what you want to do then create the list in SharePoint, export the list form from SharePoint into Infopath (so that you have the list fields as your main connection) then write code to do whatever you want to do i.e. retrieve data from the database and add to the list.